# Redux change a state from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning redux and I'm currently having trouble accessing stored state (id) in my components. I have a Footer component that has a button that's supposed to change the state in the Layout component. However I can't seem to access the state in Footer. any advice on what I could be doing wrong? thanks!

action.js

```
export function actionFunction(id) {
  return {
    type: "change/id",
    payload: id,
  };
}
```

reducer.js

```
function reducer(state = focusedTab, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "change/id":
        return {
          focusedTab: action.id,
        };
    }
    return state;
}
export default reducer;
```

Footer.js

```
export function Footer({...}) {
    const foo = () => {
        console.log("test " + id);
        useDispatch.dispatch(actionFunction(456));
    }
    return(<Button onClick={foo}>Click me</Button>);
}
```

Layout.js

```
export class Layout extends Component {
    this.state = {
        id: 123,
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
        id: state.id,
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, props) {...}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

Comment: `useDispatch.dispatch(actionFunction(456));` this is not how you use a hook. I would recommend checking out the redux/react-redux docs for guidance on using the library

Comment: sorry that should be the action instead

Comment: Besides agreeing with @BrianThompson's comment regarding *how* to use the `useDispatch` hook, what "state" are you trying to access in the `Footer` component? Please [edit] to clarify in better detail what the specific issue is, and include a complete [mcve] of all the relevant code you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

In my view your reducer logic seems to be incorrect. It's currently returning an object with a focusedTab property. It should just return the action.id. You may try to Update the reducer like this:

```
function reducer(state = focusedTab, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "change/id":
            return action.payload; // assuming payload is the id
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

There may be more problem i'm not sure now, if you provide more details I may help you.